# “You don't strike a woman even with a flower”

Tags: women, ethics

There’s a proverb ***“You don’t strike a woman even with a flower”*** (or *… (your) wife …*; at least *“ženu ani květinou neuhodíš”* in Czech language/culture — there's also a comedy [movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061215) based on that).

Ethics author [Guth-Jarkovský](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1283803) in his 1914 book *Společenský katechismus* (*“Social catechism”*) claims (without any reference), that it's an Indian proverb.

I might have seen a mention elsewhere that it’s related to Ashoka. After I was unable confirm  with available translations of his [edicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edicts_of_Ashoka), I decided to ask here, whether someone knows more about that.

Comment: There is a verse in Kularnava Tantra which says exactly the same. You can find it from this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24632/4732

Comment: @Rickross नमस्कार

Comment: Hello and Namaskar. Welcome to the site!