# Should a woman always be respected , even if she has done wrong thing and is a bad woman?

Tags: women

Since only women can give birth, without them world can't exist.
One man produces millions of sperms in one time and only few men's sperm is sufficient for the world to exist.

But women, they are the only one who can give birth to the child and only through them the world can exist.
Till this date no artificial womb has been developed. At least until then, women are the gods of the world.

So, because of above reason, the place of woman is at the top of the world.
Perhaps because of this reason, it is compulsory for women to get married but men can also remain unmarried.

So, my question is -

Is it true that a [woman should always be respected](https://youtu.be/97U4dufhcqg?feature=shared&t=1015) even if she has done wrong thing ?

Is there any such thing written in scriptures ?

Comment: Related to or duplicate of -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24628/4732

Comment: No Bhishma implies in Anusasana Parva two types

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a thing written in scripture.
Read [Under which circumstances physical punishment to wife is allowed?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24628/under-which-circumstances-physical-punishment-to-wife-is-allowed)

Here is an additional quote.

> Pay respect to womanhood, as they are all born of the family of the
> Divine Mother. **Punish them not in however mild a manner**, whatever the
> transgression. Their excellences, not failings, are to be stressed.

**Kularnava Tantra, Worship, Readings by M.P. Pandit**

Answer (score 0):

Just being a woman does not justify getting respect. One must deserve (or earn) the respect by doing good Karma. Please do not confuse yourself between - respecting Womanhood and respecting a particular women. Respecting womanhood does not mean respecting all women irrespective of their karma.