# Are women closer to God than men?

Tags: women

Are women closer to god than men ?

I am asking this as in general it is seen that women are more devoted towards god than men. They pray to god more often. They take religion, dharmgurus, rituals etc more seriously than men.

In my observation even modern hindu women are more religious and they too pray to god more than any traditional men.

Yeah, there are some women who are atheists but they are very rare.
I know some women also leave hinduism when they marry man of some other religion. But most of the time it is because of brainwashing.And it is recent pheneomenon only. Such thing didn't exist in the past.

But in general, most women are very much devoted towards gods.

Also in my other post ,I have detailed on why women because of their ability to give birth are literally [the gods of the earth.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57924/should-a-woman-always-be-respected-even-if-she-has-done-wrong-thing-and-is-a-b)

Is there **any such thing written in the scriptures** that women are more closer to God ?

Comment: no not at all although one could make the argument, that women have no rights ascribed to them in a ritual context, and Vedic knowledge while applied to them isn't necessarily prescribed for them means they are closer, but in another sense. How I see it is men are on the roof and women are the pillars. The roof is external and must gain the divine knowledge through a guru and the pillars are supporting that learning. Forget Shudras though although this is an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Women are not closer to God than men.

> **I am the same towards all beings.** None is hateful, and none, dear to
> Me. But those who worship Me with devotion dwell in Me, and I too
> dwell in them.

**Gita 9.29**

Answer (score 1):

**I think,** yes. As the scriptures sats in chronological order the following.:

Taittriya Upanishad.:

> मातृदेवो भव । पितृदेवो भव । आचार्यदेवो भव । अतिथिदेवो भव ।
>
> I-xi-2: Let your mother be a goddess unto you. Let your father be a god unto you. Let your teacher be a god unto you. Let your guest be a god unto you.

Brahma vaivarta purana , Krishna janma khanda , Chapter 52. Verse 34-35a.:

> जगन्माता च प्रकृतिः पुरुषश्च जगत्पिता ।। ३४ ।। गरीयसी त्रिजगतां माता शतगुणैः पितुः ।।
>
> Prakriti happens to be the mother of the universe and Purusha the father. In all the worlds, the glory of the mother is hundred times more than that of the father.

I hope this helps. Prd..